# How to set an ID on the target of an HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I need to set a `window.id` on the `target` of an HTML `form`. The motivation is for Selenium automation tests. How would I access this `window`?

Comment: By *target of an HTML form*, do you mean the server-side script identified in the `action=""` attribute, or something else?

Comment: In my instance, I mean the new window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In other words, you have a new window already created and you want to set the target of your form to that new window?  Instead of creating your new window with _blank, name it something.  Then set the target of your form to it.

Answer (score 0):

Add it inline with the `<form>` tag:

```
<form id="myId">
</form>
```

Comment: isn't that just the form element? I didn't think that id would apply to the target (in this case a new window) of the form.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the best answer but you could try passing the id you want through a  in the form and then on the new page grab the value and set window.id accordingly.